# How to read epub files using javascript

Tags: javascript, epub, client-side

How to read epub files using javascript?

I tried epubjs but thats not suited for my requirement. Is any other alternative javascript libraries available?

Comment: Did you tried https://github.com/augustl/js-epub

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Readium Foundation just released Readium Web Components: see http://readium.org/news/announcing-readiumjs-a-javascript-library-for-browser-based-epub-3-reading (code: https://github.com/readium/Readium-Web-Components )

Alternatively, you might want to have a look at FuturePress: http://www.futurepress.org/ (code: https://github.com/fchasen/epub.js/ )

Finally, TEA also has something you might find interesting: https://github.com/TEA-ebook/teabook-open-reader

Comment: The Github Redium link changed so best to go to https://github.com/readium/ for information on that project.

Answer (score 3):

Quite old question, `TreineticEpubReader` is a popular fork of `readium-js-viewer` authored by me, it provides a very simple api to interact with epub files[image],

https://github.com/Treinetic/TreineticEpubReader

Library is pure javascript so you can blend and mix with any modern framework, here is a sample code, you can also look at the `sample` folder inside the `dist` to find a working demo

```
<div id="epub-reader-frame"></div>
```

```js
var exControls = TreineticEpubReader.handler();
exControls.registerEvent("onEpubLoadSuccess", function () {

});

exControls.registerEvent("onEpubLoadFail", function () {

});

exControls.registerEvent("onTOCLoaded", function (hasTOC) {
    if (!hasTOC) {
       let toc =  exControls.getTOCJson();
    }
    // you can use following api calls after this
    /**
    exControls.hasNextPage()
    exControls.nextPage();
    exControls.hasPrevPage()
    exControls.prevPage();
    exControls.makeBookMark();
    exControls.changeFontSize(int);
    exControls.changeColumnMaxWidth(int);
    exControls.setTheme("theme-id-goes-here");
    exControls.setScrollMode("scroll-type-id-goes-here");
    exControls.setDisplayFormat("display-format-id-goes-here");

    extcontrols.getRecommendedFontSizeRange()
    extcontrols.getRecommendedColumnWidthRange()
    var list = extcontrols.getAvailableThemes();
    var list = extcontrols.getAvailableScrollModes();
    var list = extcontrols.getAvailableDisplayFormats();
    var settings = extcontrols.getCurrentReaderSettings();
    **/
});

var config = TreineticEpubReader.config();
config.jsLibRoot = "src/ZIPJS/";

TreineticEpubReader.create("#epub-reader-frame");
TreineticEpubReader.open("assets/epub/epub_1.epub");
```

Comment: Judging by the nicknames it seems you are related to the author of the fork, you just forgot to mention it, correct?

Comment: Yes our company forked it from the main repo and improved to to reach this level does it need to mention that I involved in developing this ? I really do not know

Comment: Simply put, you should do it to provide fair information -- there is a difference between "I use this great lib" and "I wrote this great lib".